# Prove that if no team loses all of its games, then at least two teams will finish the tournament with the same number of wins

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction, pigeonhole-principle

Prove the following statement by induction.
Suppose that eight hockey teams are entered in a round-robin tournament, which means that each
team plays every other team exactly once. Assume that no ties are allowed (e.g., all ties will go
to a penalty shootout). Prove that if no team loses all of its games, then at least two teams will
finish the tournament with the same number of wins.

Comment: It's not induction, it's the pigeonhole principle.

Comment: Sorry, I mean the question should be proof by induction

Comment: You mean the assignment says to prove this by induction?  That doesn't seem reasonable, since there is no variable number.

Comment: Yes, and it also said I can use the Pigeonhole Principle.

Comment: What are the possible numbers of games that a team can win?

Comment: It didn't say. I guess it is 7.

Comment: Sorry for the comment I just deleted.  You're correct, it's 7.  Now what does the pigeonhole principle tell you?

Comment: for all n ≥ 1, if n + 1 or more items are placed in at most n boxes, then at least one of the boxes must contain at least two items.

Answer (score 0):

8 teams, each team can have 1 to 7 wins.
Pigeon hole the teams into the number of wins.

Comment: could you please explain more specifically? I will really appreciate that.

Comment: What are the boxes and who are the pigeons?  @JingzongLu